# Haskell, documentation for unlabeled command line arguments in optparse-generic

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, optparse-generic

I'm using [optparse-generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic) to parse the command line arguments of a program called `example`. I have a datatype with an unnamed field. For example:

```
data Unlabeled = Unlabeled String deriving (Generic, Show)
```

This generates a program which can be called as follows: `./exmaple "foo"`. However, for the user, there is no documentation what the `String`-parameter is about. In particular, `./example --help` does not give any valuable information about this positional `String` argument `./example` expects.

Using named datatypes (record syntax), it is possible to add documentation to the datatype. For example

```
data Labeled = Labeled {name :: String <?> "Select the foo"} deriving (Generic, Show)
```

This generates help text for the program. For example, when called `./example --help`, it will display `--name STRING    Select the foo`.

How can I add documentation to unnamed datatypes in the same way as I can do for record-syntax-datatypes?

Comment: `data Labeled = Labeled (String <?> "Select the foo")`  will give you `...STRING                   Select the foo...` in the `--help` message.

Comment: Ahh, parenthesis. How stupid of me. @user2407038, could you please post this as regular answer so I can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data `Labeled = Labeled (String <?> "Select the foo")` will give you

```
...
STRING     Select the foo
...
```

in the `--help` message. To perhaps clarify, the `<?>` is simply a type constructor, it is just syntactically an operator. Maybe fun fact: you can write `` data X = X (Int `Either` Bool) `` as well.